# Is it possible to implement concept of lazy loading/ Eager loading on memory object like List (Not with DB objects)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, lazy-loading, eager-loading

i am just asking this question to clear some confusion about .Net/Entity Framework that is it possible to implement lazy loading/Eager loading concepts on memory objects as we do for Database object. 
I know that Entity Framework provides this feature inbuilt for Database entities. But can we use same approach (with or without using Entity Framework) for in memory object like class objects/list etc.

**`For example:`**

```
    public class Student
    {
        public Student() { }
        public Student(int studentId, string name, Address address, List<Subject> subjects)
        {
            StudentId = studentId;
            Name = name;
            Address = address;
            Subjects = subjects;
        }

        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    }
    public class Address
    {
        public string AddressLineOne { get; set; }
        public string AddressLineTwo { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
    }
    public class Subject
    {
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }
        public string SubjectName { get; set; }
    }
```

I Created object of student class with all properties initialized:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Student std = new Student(1, "Stduent1", new Address { AddressLineOne = "#118 D-Road", City = "CHD", State = "CHD" },
            new List<Subject> {
                new Subject{ SubjectId=1, SubjectName="History" },
                new Subject{ SubjectId=2, SubjectName="English" }
            });

        return View();
    }
```

[image: All properties are initialized and filled]
Is there any way that we can load this Subject list and Address Object on demand only.

One option is that i can initiaize Address and List of Subject only when i need it. But is it possible the way EF implement lazy loading.

I have studied about Lazy< T > but didn't get much clarify for the same.

Please provide your valuable feedback/suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let every type of members be an IEnumerable and use queries like Select(x => x..) to get the desired result even though it might be a IEnumerable with one item.. you will end up loading everything as lazy as possible and you ll never end up fighting against variable == null

Comment: @devhedgehog, sorry i didn't get your point, could you please explain a little more.

Comment: Lazy loading for in-memory only structures doesn't make a great deal of *sense*, unless the data that you supply later is entirely random - that data has to come from somewhere. So what are you going to do - store all of the data inside the `Student` object until the `Address` is requested and then populate it? what form will that data within the `Student` object take? Doesn't this then leave you just with two representations of an address when you only actually need one, and it's already available.

Comment: @Gerry see Ilya Chernomordik answer

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure why do you want lazy loading of something that is already in memory, but you can do it with IEnumerable if I understood what you want to achieve correctly:

```
public class Student
{
    public IEnumerable<Subject> Subjects
    {
        get
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                yield return new Subject(); 
            }                
        }
    }

}
```

You don't need yield return, but it all depends on how you get your Subjects. So each time MoveNext is called (e.g. inside foreach) your code will be called and you'll be able to fetch whatever you need.